# using HTML select tag name in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have an array which I used in the  tag name :

```
<?php 

  echo "<td><select name='search[$field]'></select>"

?>
```

but how do I write the name in Javascript?

For example

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

document.formname.---.options.length = 0;

</script>
```

How should I write in the "---" ?

Is it something like this?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

document.formname.search[$field].options.length = 0;

</script>
```

Comment: `document.formname['search[$field]'].options.length = 0;`

Comment: ya know, `language="javascript"` has not been require to use for almost 10 years now .. you might look into the age or quality of your tutorial.

Comment: The language attribute has been deprecated since HTML 4, so yeah, worth removing.

Answer (score 1):

Give the select elemenent an id and use it to reference the element:

```
<?php 
  echo "<td><select name='search[$field]' id='mySelect'></select>"
?>

<script>
var select =  document.getElementById('mySelect');
```

Comment: Form controls must have a name to be sucessful, otherwise they aren't submitted with the form.

Comment: But you don't need an id, you can select the element using the name that it must already have. If you must have a name, it is a lot more convenient to set set the name and id to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Where the name of a form control isn't a valid identifier, Use square bracket notation:

```
document.formname.elements['search[$field]'].options.length = 0;
```

Note that the full, formal method is:

```
document.forms['formName'].elements['elementName'].options.length = 0;
```

However each is made a named property of its "parent" so where the names are all valid identifiers:

```
document.formName.elementName;
```

works, and where they aren't:

```
document['formName']['elementName'];
```

will do the trick. Also use square brackets where the names are held in variables:

```
var fn = 'form[Name]';
```

can be used as:

```
var theForm = document[fn];
```

or

```
var theForm = document.forms[fn];
```

Comment: `$field` is a PHP evaluated variable, not a string!

Comment: Just reflecting the OP's code. If server sdie code is posted, the answer should probably reflect that. It's irrelevant to the answer anyway - the "[" and "]" characters are illegal in javascript identifiers so must be used with square bracket notation, the "$" character isn't.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

document.formname.search[<?php echo $field; ?>].options.length = 0;

</script>
```